# Custom legend turn off marker facecolor

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am plotting some data where a line of best fit and the data itself need to have the same legend. The data points are plotted with hollow circles, so I wish to have a legend with a hollow circle with a line passing all the way through it. I have made this, but when I run it the legend still fills in the circle with color.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
#============================================
legend1 = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='m', markerfacecolor='none', markeredgecolor='m', markerfacecoloralt='none', marker='o',
                          markersize=10, label='data')
#============================================
x = np.random.randint(11, size=100)
y = np.random.randint(11, size=100)
#============================================
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 10, 1000), np.linspace(0, 10, 1000), 'm-')
plt.scatter(x, y, s = 80, facecolors = 'none', edgecolors = 'm', marker = 'o')
plt.legend(handles = [legend1], loc = "upper left")
plt.show()
#============================================
```

Comment: On my end the legend appears with a hollow circle.

Comment: Are you running a current version of matplotlib? `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)` should print out something like `3.2.1`